# What code editor is being used here?

Tags: ide, editor

Can any one tell me what code editor is being used in this picture? Saw it on a blog post, looks nice

http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beliefv2/blog-images/craftcms-boilerplate-assets-structure.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's called [CodeBox](https://www.codebox.io/). Looks pretty good actually, might take a look at it myself.

Comment: Ah great! Thank you. Yea just looking at it now, looks pretty nifty, I like the idea of a combined cloud and desktop editor, also very nice ui :)